# Determining the motion of a classical particle and quantum particle in a given potential with a given initial position and energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation

[image: Here is the question.]

How do I go about solving this?

I know bound states require the energy to be less than the potential while scattering states require the energy to be greater than the potential.

I also know that quantum particles exist in areas where a classical particle would not. [image: Here is the second question with the quantum particle.]

Here is the second question, again what steps should I take to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try to look at the maximum value of the potential and draw your conclusions.

Comment: Do you mean plotting the function for v(x) and then looking at the different energies specified by the problem for the x=0 region? @DavideMorgante

Comment: It's not necessary to plot it, it sure can help but it's not the right way of doing it. What I mean is exactly what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: And note that the general shape of the potential can be easily understood without plotting it: it's just a sine, squared, divided an always positive, symmetric function.